# Disable Ability to Edit RecordType

Tags: page-layout, security, record-type, field-level-security, read-only

I have a custom object with a Record Type that is read-only on the page layout but I can still make updates to the Record Type on the page. Why is this? I want to make the field un-editable, is there an additional step to making this field actually read-only?

See attached images

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are a System Admin, Read/Only requirements on the Page Layout do not apply. Rest assured they do work fine for non Sys-Admins.